# API - status response

Tags: c#, web-services, api, architecture

In regards to Web service API,

You (developer) do a "GetPhoneNumberList" and the user has not added a phone number to his account, do you expect the API to response with status = "success" or "failure"?

No records will be returned because there is nothing to return.

(I would expect status to be success, since its not the developers fault)?

Comment: What type of service are you referring to? The semantics of a RESTful service would be different to say a SOAP-based service. In a REST service I would expect to call HTTP GET /User/{id}/PhoneNumber and if it wasn't present I'd want a HTTP not found error.

Comment: I agree with that returns success, and who invokes the service evaluates how process the list ...  if number of records is 0 or obj is null...

Comment: Not really sure how to give an answer, especially since there is a lot we do not know: what is the full signature of the method? are "success" and "failure" the only two results?  what conventions are used elsewhere in the service/project? what type of web service is it?  do you return other information along with success/failure?  Does the phone number list exist but is empty, or does it not exist?  Does the preceding distinction matter?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what information you did give I can give an opinion, but it is not a very informed one since I do not know all the details.

Judging solely by the name of your method I conclude you are writing an API for retrieval.  If I call `GetPhoneNumberList` I expect to receive some sort of sequence containing zero or more items.  Thus, it seems perfectly reasonable that you might successfully retrieve zero phone numbers.  Otherwise, how do I tell the difference between a user who set no phone numbers, and a program/network/database/security/etc error while retrieving the phone number?